# How to return a value from inside an interator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I want to return true or false.

Inside the function I iterate through some elements on the page and check their values.

But if I put a return statement inside the iterator, it will return from the anonymous function right?  (and not the outer function).

```
function someElementHasZeroValue() {
  $('.some-class').each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == '0'){
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

So this function always returns false no matter what.

What is the best way to do this?  The solution below seems to work but it doesn't seem very elegant.

```
function someElementHasZeroValue() {
  elements_found_with_zero_value = 0;
  $('.some-class').each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == '0'){
      elements_found_with_zero_value += 1;
    }
  });

  if(elements_found_with_zero_value > 0){
    return true;
  }else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

More generally, does anyone know why Javascript requires you to iterate through elements with an anonymous function as opposed to a normal iterator like most languages, or is there some way to do it I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using jQuery, not pure Javascript.  You could do a normal loop:

```
function someElementHasZeroValue() {
    var selection = $('.some-class');
    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        if ($(selection[i]).html() === '0') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could do this in a more jQuery-like way:

```
function someElementHasZeroValue() {
    return $('.some-class').filter(function(){
        return $(this).html() === '0';
    }).length > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a solution like yours, but it could be a little simpler.

```
function someElementHasZeroValue() {
      // this is the return value, initialized as false
  var ret = false;
  $('.some-class').each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == '0'){
      ret =  true; // set it to true
    }
  });
  return ret;  // return the value of "ret"
}
```

Additionally, if you wanted to break the `.each()` loop when the `if()` succeeds, you can add a `return false;`, which will break the loop without returning the function.

```
    if($(this).html() == '0') {
      ret = true;  // set it to true
      return false; // break the each() loop
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, JavaScript doesn't require this of you. It's jQuery that is doing it. With JavaScript you could do normal for loops and return out of it that way. jQuery's `each()` will incrementally return a jQuery object for all matches of the selector you use. You could do something like this:

```
function someElementHasZeroValue() {
  var returnValue = false;
  $('.some-class').each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == '0'){
      returnValue = true;
    }
  });
  return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function someElementHasZeroValue() {
  var result = false;

  $('.some-class').each(function() {
     if (($this).html() == '0') {
       result = true;
       return false;
     }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Please note that `return false` inside `each` callback means that we should interrupt iterations (see jQuery documentation), it's similar to `break` in "normal cycles".

Also always prefer variables declaration with `var` (use local instead of global variables).